# How to calculate gross margin in Postgresql with needing multiple formulas?

Tags: postgresql

I am still learning postgresql after my company converted from MySQL and running into an issue with this report I was asked to make, which I would like to show a single value as a percentage showing our gross margin.

I need to calculate our profit margin which would be `invoices.total -earnings.amount -jobs.off_cost / invoices.total` . With our data types, I have to divide anything currency by 100.

I'm also struggling to figure out the best way to do this, as for every job a field calculating the earnings.amount will populate and I cannot remove, but if a job has an "off cost" which is often very much more, it will count both amounts as having been spent, when in those cases it was only the "off cost" that was paid/spent.

This report is also being filtered by time ranges, states, and company names.

With the code I have below it is pulling a very off number than expected (in billions, which we definitely aren't making.)

I appreciate any and all help that can be provided!

```
SELECT SUM( (invoices.total) - (earnings.amount) - (jobs.off_app_server_cost) / (invoices.total) /100) as "Profit Margin"
FROM law_firms
LEFT JOIN jobs on law_firms.id = jobs.law_firm_id 
LEFT JOIN invoices on law_firms.id = invoices.law_firm_id 
LEFT JOIN states on jobs.state_id = states.id
LEFT JOIN earnings on jobs.id = earnings.job_id
WHERE invoices.deleted_at IS NULL 
AND law_firms.deleted_at IS NULL
AND CAST(invoices.created_at AS DATE) BETWEEN {daterange.start} AND {daterange.end} 
AND law_firms.id = {Law_Firm}
AND states.name = {State_Name}
AND invoices.total != 0.00
```

| invoice total | earnings amount | off cost | margin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 30 | N/A | 70 |
| 200 | 40 | 300 | -70 |
| 300 | 50 | 400 | -33 |

Comment: Sample data and desired results will help here.

Comment: 1) This '...as every job will have earnings.amount tied to it, but sometimes that isn't relevant as if it also has the jobs.off_cost, ...' needs more explanation. 2) Could this `- (earnings.amount) - (jobs.off_app_server_cost)` not be changed to `- (earnings.amount   + jobs.off_app_server_cost)`? 3) And should it not be `(SUM((invoices.total) - (earnings.amount + jobs.off_app_server_cost))/SUM(invoices.total)) /100`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Sorry for it being slightly vague. Every job has a fixed cost (earnings.amount) tied to it that automatically populates, but not every job has an "off cost". Sometimes a job will have an "off cost" that is more than the earnings.amount cost, but the earnings.amount cost will be still be counted and show up for the job.

Comment: @Stu i have updated my post to clarify a few things, and also include sample data.

Comment: Huh? What happens if there is no "off cost", is it null? If there is an "of cost" is it a marginal cost above the "amount_cost" or the total of "amount_cost" and some additional costs? As @Stu said example data would be helpful. Also does my 3) point in my original comment work?

Comment: Do not provide data as an image copy and paste as text. Preferably in [Table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) format.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver apologies, I've edited using the formatting as best as I could in table formatting. Yes, if there is no off cost, it is null. It's a set cost put in, and is often much higher than the earnings.amount that is automatically generated for each job. In a perfect world, if an off cost was put in, the earnings.amount cost would not also populate in the data, but this is what I'm unfortunately working with.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I also tried your formula and it came back with the answer of "0".

Comment: 1) Probably because if `off_app_server_cost` is NULL the result of the calculation will be `NULL` e.g `select 10-5-null; null`. You will need a `coalesce(off_app_server_cost, 0)`. 2) How did you get margin of  `-33` for third row: `select (300 - (50 + 400))/300.0; 0.5000`. 3) Try with  `...SUM(invoices.total)) /100.0`. You may be seeing integer division result. 4) So if both `off_cost` and `earnings.amount` you are over estimating costs?